# Problem with processing word document java

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

i  need to replace some fields in Word Document file in java.I am using Apache Poi library  , i am using this code to replace words.

```
for (XWPFParagraph p : doc.getParagraphs()) {
                List<XWPFRun> runs = p.getRuns();
                if (runs != null) {
                    for (XWPFRun r : runs) {
                        String text = r.getText(0);
                        if (text != null)  {
                            System.out.println(text);
                            if (text.contains("[Title]")) {
                                text = text.replace("[Title]", wordBody.getTitle());//your content
                                r.setText(text, 0);
                            }if(text.contains("[Ref_no]")){
                                text=text.replace("[Ref_no]",wordBody.getRefNumber());
                                r.setText(text,0);
                            }
                            if(text.contains("[In_date]")){
                                text=text.replace("[In_date]",wordBody.getDate());
                                r.setText(text,0);
                            }if(text.contains("[FirstName]")){
                                text=text.replace("[FirstName]",wordBody.getFirstName());
                                r.setText(text,0);
                            }if(text.contains("[MiddleName]")){
                                text=text.replace("[MiddleName]",wordBody.getMiddleName());
                                r.setText(text,0);
                            }if(text.contains("[Vehicle_Type]")){
                                text=text.replace("[Vehicle_Type]",wordBody.getVehicleType());
                                r.setText(text,0);
                            }if(text.contains("[Reg_No]")){
                                text=text.replace("[Reg_No]",wordBody.getRegNumber());
                                r.setText(text,0);
                            }if(text.contains("[Location]")){
                                text=text.replace("[Location]",wordBody.getLocation());
                                r.setText(text,0);
                            }if(text.contains("[Issuer_Name]")){
                                text=text.replace("[Issuer_Name]",wordBody.getLocation());
                                r.setText(text,0);
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

So i mentioned that not all words a replaced and i didn't know how to fix it , then i printed out all text what i get and i got something like that

```
This is to certify that [Title] [FirstName] [
MiddleName
] [Surname] has purchased [
Vehicle_Type
] 
having registration [
Reg_No
] from our [Location] Showroom.
Issued By,
[
Issuer
```

So i need replace fields in []  brackets and some of them as [Surname] a printed okay but some of them as [MIddleName] are changing line and i think that s way its not working .

This - is my word text

[image]

I parsing docx file .
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a look on your screen shot, you will see the red wavy line under MiddleName, Vehicle_Type and Reg_No. That means, that `Word` has detected a possible spelling problem here. This also is stored in the file and that's why the texts [MIddleName], [Vehicle_Type] and [Reg_No] are not together in one text run  with their surrounding brackets. The brackets are in their own text runs and also the texts together with the possible spelling problem marked.

This is a well known problem and some libraries already try solving this by detecting the text variables a more complex way than only searching them in text runs. There is [templ4docx](https://github.com/jsolve/templ4docx) for example.

But my preferred way is another. `Word` for a long time provides using text form fields. See [Working with Form Fields](https://wordribbon.tips.net/T008303_Working_with_Form_Fields.html). Note the legacy form fields are meant, not the ActiveX ones.

See [Replace text templates inside .docx (Apache POI, Docx4j or other)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49678959/replace-text-templates-inside-docx-apache-poi-docx4j-or-other/49705552#49705552) for an example.

Modified example for your case:

WordTemplate.docx:

[image]

All gray fields are legacy text form fields inserted from developer tab. In their `Text Form Field Options` the `Bookmark:` names are `Text1`, `Text2`, ... and default texts are set as needed.

Code:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject;
import org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlCursor;
import org.apache.xmlbeans.SimpleValue;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

public class WordReplaceTextInFormFields {

 private static void replaceFormFieldText(XWPFDocument document, String ffname, String text) {
  boolean foundformfield = false;
  for (XWPFParagraph paragraph : document.getParagraphs()) {
   for (XWPFRun run : paragraph.getRuns()) {
    XmlCursor cursor = run.getCTR().newCursor();
    cursor.selectPath("declare namespace w='http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main' .//w:fldChar/@w:fldCharType");
    while(cursor.hasNextSelection()) {
     cursor.toNextSelection();
     XmlObject obj = cursor.getObject();
     if ("begin".equals(((SimpleValue)obj).getStringValue())) {
      cursor.toParent();
      obj = cursor.getObject();
      obj = obj.selectPath("declare namespace w='http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main' .//w:ffData/w:name/@w:val")[0];
      if (ffname.equals(((SimpleValue)obj).getStringValue())) {
       foundformfield = true;
      } else {
       foundformfield = false;
      }
     } else if ("end".equals(((SimpleValue)obj).getStringValue())) {
      if (foundformfield) return;
      foundformfield = false;
     }
    }
    if (foundformfield && run.getCTR().getTList().size() > 0) {
     run.getCTR().getTList().get(0).setStringValue(text);
     foundformfield = false;
//System.out.println(run.getCTR());
    }
   }
  }
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("WordTemplate.docx"));

  replaceFormFieldText(document, "Text1", "Mrs.");
  replaceFormFieldText(document, "Text2", "Janis");
  replaceFormFieldText(document, "Text3", "Lyn");
  replaceFormFieldText(document, "Text4", "Joplin");
  replaceFormFieldText(document, "Text5", "Mercedes Benz");
  replaceFormFieldText(document, "Text6", "1234-56-789");
  replaceFormFieldText(document, "Text7", "Stuttgart");

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("WordReplaceTextInFormFields.docx");
  document.write(out);
  out.close();
  document.close();
 }
}
```

This code is tested using `apache poi 4.1.0` and needs the full jar of all of the schemas `ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar` as mentioned in [FAQ-N10025](https://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10025).

Result:

[image]

Note the gray background of the text fields is only visible in `GUI`. It will not be printed out by default.

Advantages:

The form field content can only be formatted as whole. So form field content will never torn apart.

The document can be protected so only filling the form fields is possible. Then the template is usable as a form in `Word` `GUI` too.

Comment: exactly what I am looking for. hard to believe this answer has only 2 upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a super-quick fix to prevent splitting text into multiple runs so that it can be recognized/read by the java program, do the following:

1. Copy the text you want in a single run
2. Paste it into notepad (removes all the docx formatting)
3. Copy and paste that text into the word document, hit Save.

It will now be inserted as one run.